# increment Form after update

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, forms

I have WordPress E-Commerce plugin installed.

In the checkout page there is input form for quantity field and update button.

Like you can type any quantity you want and update product price

Form looks like this for every product:

```
<td class="wpsc_product_quantity wpsc_product_quantity_<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>">
  <form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_option( 'shopping_cart_url' ) ); ?>" method="post" class="adjustform qty">
    <input class="span1" type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo wpsc_cart_item_quantity(); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="wpsc_update_quantity" value="true" />
    <input class="btn btn-new btn-new-red" type="submit" value="u" name="submit" />
  </form>
</td>
```

My task is to make two buttons like "plus" and "minus" which will submit this form +1 or -1

can I make it with php or javascript using this form?

hope I described what I want in normal manners

Comment: yes you increase of decrease value trough javascript

Comment: Definitely do this with JavaScript. No need to post back to your server to increment a field on the page

Comment: How? :D I wanted to use php because I think it will be easier not digging into other wp e-commerce code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
    function changeQuantity(v){
        document.getElementById('quantity').value=parseInt(v)+parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value);


    }
</script>


<td class="wpsc_product_quantity wpsc_product_quantity_<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>">
    <form action="<?php echo esc_url(get_option('shopping_cart_url')); ?>" method="post" class="adjustform qty">
        <!-- Add id -->
        <input class="span1" type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo wpsc_cart_item_quantity(); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo wpsc_the_cart_item_key(); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="wpsc_update_quantity" value="true" />
        <input class="btn btn-new btn-new-red" type="submit" value="u" name="submit" />
        <!--    New added code-->
        <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="changeQuantity(1);">Plus</a>  <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="changeQuantity(-1);">Minus</a>
    </form>
</td>
```

Comment: I have only create how can increase or decrease quantity

Comment: Whenever using `parseInt`, you should always supply the second `radix` parameter as 10, to avoid octal number issues: `parseInt(v, 10)`

Comment: yes but it's not what I want. I want to update my cart, it only updates the value. it there a way to click submit button at the same time and hide it's input (submit)

Comment: Colin second argument is optional http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: I'm sorry but not what i wanted.
tried remaking it, even did .click method and others things but works totally other way

Comment: can i see you project link

Comment: I have it locally.
<p> found this, totally same plugin I'm using:
http://ecomm.destinymanifestation.com/?wpsc-product=twidget-1
<p> press add to cart and go to products page -> checkout